# immer's original function is returning undefined for a proxy object

Tags: immer.js, redux-toolkit

`console.log(state, original(state))`

prints:

`Proxy {0: {…}} undefined`

I'm stuck... if I had more time, I'd go into the source to figure out how to re-write `original` to not fail, but I'm pressed to fix a bug.

Why would original return undefined, if the object is a proxy object?

Important note, this is in a redux toolkit slice function.

Comment: I don't know this library, but I wonder if more detail might be helpful, to get readers up to speed with the problem?

Comment: Same issue here! `original` checks whether a particular `symbol` is present in the object, which the proxy does not have

Comment: are you by chance using typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean `console.log(draft, original(draft))`?

In Immer 7 you will get an explicit exception if you pass in an undrafted object, rather than getting `undefined` back, which should help you to catch such problems earlier.

The `symbol` issue only occurred when using polyfilled symbols and has been fixed in Immer 7 as well.